# How to properly implement asynchronicity in web api 2

Tags: c#, task-parallel-library, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2

I've been seeing some conflicting information on the subject, and I would like to achieve some clarity here.

Originally, you would have Web Api actions such as:

- `Model Action();`
- `HttpResponseMessage Action();`

Then, with the addition of TPL enhancements to Web Api, you could have

- `Task<Model> Action();`
- `Task<HttpResponseMessage> Action();`

And supposedly, ASP.NET would be smart enough to handle those by waiting for the task to finish, and by releasing the thread that picked up the request in the mean time.

*Beautiful!* Everything was simple in the world. But now, with Web API 2, there is a the addition of `IHttpActionResult`, a third case, which provides the `Task<HttpResponseMessage> ExecuteAsync()` method.

First off, if you inspect implementations of `IHttpActionResult`, you see that every `ExecuteAsync` actually just returns `Task.FromResult` (not async at all, and does not seem like it would give any performance gain over synchronously returning `HttpResponseMessage`). Second, I see people recommending to use `Task<IHttpActionResult>`, which seems entirely redundant. I even see a handful of people suggesting that you combine these approaches and return `Task.Factory.StartNew(..)` from your action, which seems kind of absurd.

So what is the correct way to use `IHttpActionResult` asynchronously? Do you simply implement your own, and do asynchronous operations there†, or do you return `Task<IHttpActionResult>`, make your method `async`, and await on IO-bound operations before calling to `return Ok()` (or equivalent)?

To be clear, I do obviously understand that simply going from `IHttpActionResult Action();` to `Task<IHttpActionResult> Action();` without  changing the method body will not help in any way. It is the intent of the `ExecuteAsync` that is a puzzle.

† https://stackoverflow.com/a/21609402/661422

Comment: Using `Task.FromResult` is an implementation detail - that is, the implementor has taken the decision not to use asynchronicity, but may decide to use it in the future, if it is warranted. Whereas there is no good way to implement a synchronous API asynchronously.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Everything was simple in the world. But now, with Web API 2, there is a the addition of `IHttpActionResult`

`IHttpActionResult` came to the world for the purpose of encapsulating the generation of `HttpResponseMessage`. This would let you encapsulate common logic for creating similar responses inside a set of classes which could be reused, easily tested, and would free the controller actions to take care of actual business logic.

> First off, if you inspect implementations of IHttpActionResult, you see that every ExecuteAsync actually just returns Task.FromResult

I'm assuming that happens because, for example,  `NotFound();` and `Ok()` extension methods simply return a constructed `HttpResponseMessage`, nothing more. Perhaps you haven't ran into real world scenarios where that would be needed.

> Second, I see people recommending to use Task, which seems entirely redundant.

You would return a `Task<IHttpActionResult>` if your action uses a naturally asynchronous operation. I don't see how that can be redundant. It is needed.

> So what is the correct way to use IHttpActionResult asynchronously?

The correct way is the same as for all async methods. Lets say you want to log every response before returning to a 3rd party logging framework, which exposes an asynchronous API via HTTP endpoint, you'd do:

```
public class LogActionResult : IHttpActionResult
{
   string uri = /* ... */

   public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   {
       var response = new HttpResponseMessage()
       {
           Content = new StringContent(_value),
           RequestMessage = _request
       };

       var httpClient = new HttpClient();
       await httpClient.PostAsJsonAsync(uri, response);

       return response;
   }
}
```

Asynchronoysly log and return the `HttpResponseMessage`. If you have no async operation, `Task.FromResult` would be perfectly fine.

Comment: So, in practice, do people go ahead and create implementations of IHttpActionResult in real world scenarios?

Answer (score 0):

I don't like the way where I need to implement vendor interfaces that changed from version to version, there are more accurate version:

```
public class FibonacciController : ApiController
{
    public IHttpActionResult Get(int fibN)
    {
        Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
        {
            var fibNResult = FibonacciHelpers.CalculateFibonacci(fibN);
        });

        return Ok();
    }
}
```